/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found
i am trying to install prismlauncher through the zip file but this shows up. helpp please im using ubuntu 16.04.7 xenial (its outdated because anything above 16.04 doesnt support my laptops legacy bios )

Ubuntu 16.04 has not been supported on this site since April 30th 2021 It is long past EOL.

FYI: The oldest machine I use in QA (Quality Assurance testing) of Ubuntu is from 2005, and it runs all releases up to and including Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. Even my current box (a 2008 dell) is legacy BIOS and runs all releases too.   You can use this site to ask questions about installing a fully supported on your hardware, but EOL or EOSS releases are off-topic here, being supported on by Canonical now (via ESM or Pro service contracts; community support ending after 5 years)

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's standard support life thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  Ubuntu PRO & Ubuntu ESM are Canonical services, and not part of community support
